# Slow T-SQL query with datediff function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query which runs fast when the date clause "and datediff(day,con2.DT_DateIncluded),'2017-01-01')<=0" in the code below isn't used in the query, but runs slowly when it is included. Though it runs fast when I run just the part "select top 2 ID_Contact...", even including the date clause. I have this query on a classic ASP application, and it can't be converted in to a stored procedure (project scope reasons). Can you help me find a way to improve the performance of the full query just by changing the query code?

```
select distinct top 10 
    ID_Contact, NO_CodCompany 
from 
    tblContacts con1 
where 
    ID_Contact in (select top 2 ID_Contact
                   from tblContacts con2 
                   inner join tblCompanies cp on con2.NO_CodCompany = cp.ID_Company
                   where con2.NO_CodCompany = con1.NO_CodCompany
                     and datediff(day, con2.DT_DateIncluded), '2017-01-01') <= 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially your query:
This is your query:

```
select distinct top 10 ID_Contact, NO_CodCompany
from tblContacts con1
where ID_Contact in (select top 2 ID_Contact
                     from tblContacts con2 inner join
                          tblCompanies cp
                          on con2.NO_CodCompany = cp.ID_Company
                     where con2.NO_CodCompany = con1.NO_CodCompany and
                           datediff(day, con2.DT_DateIncluded), '2017-01-01') <= 0
                    );
```

My first suggestion is to change the `datediff()` to a simple date comparison:

```
select distinct top 10 ID_Contact, NO_CodCompany
from tblContacts con1
where ID_Contact in (select top 2 ID_Contact
                     from tblContacts con2 inner join
                          tblCompanies cp
                          on con2.NO_CodCompany = cp.ID_Company
                     where con2.NO_CodCompany = con1.NO_CodCompany and
                           con2.DT_DateIncluded < '2017-01-02'
                    );
```

Then, I would remove the `JOIN` in the subquery.  I'm not 100% sure this is exactly equivalent, because that might depend on nuances in the data:

```
select distinct top 10 ID_Contact, NO_CodCompany
from tblContacts con1
where con1.ID_Contact in (select top 2 con2.ID_Contact
                          from tblCompanies cp
                          where con1.NO_CodCompany = cp.ID_Company and
                                con1.DT_DateIncluded < '2017-01-02' 
                         );
```

Then, if you can remove the `select distinct` in the outermost query, you should do that.

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff, and thank you for your SUPER quick response. Although I have to say that it keeps running slow after these changes suggested, I will keep them in the code, since they might add some performance anyways... cheers!

Comment: `DATEDIFF('2017-01-01 11:59:50', '2017-01-01')` still has a value of `0`. Equivalent code would be `DT_DateIncluded < '20170102'` instead of `DT_DateIncluded < '20170101'`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn . . . It is not clear that a field called `DateIncluded` would have a time component -- although that is quite reasonable if the "dt" prefix is meant to imply "datetime".  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
con2.DT_DateIncluded < '20170102'
```

It's better because it still allows the server to make use of any indexes on the `DT_DateIncluded` column. Currently, this is not possible. Even worse, the query is probably having to run that DATEDIFF() function on every record in the table.

Note that this *is* equivalent to what you posted, even if it might not match what you intended. I suspect `con2.DT_DateIncluded < '20170101'` is closer to what you really meant.

I also suspect you could do this either without the 2nd instance of tblContacts or with a windowing function to get much better results, or at least by using `JOIN` instead of `IN` to filter the results.

Finally, for historical reasons, when entering a date-only value, you should use the *unseparated* date format as described here:

> [The ultimate guide to the datetime datatypes](http://www.karaszi.com/sqlserver/info_datetime.asp)

For date/time values, you can still use the separated `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` you're used to, but if you only have the date part, `yyyymmdd` is better.

---

Based on this comment:

> My goal with this query is to obtain contacts from companies but limited to "n" contacts per company

You should look into the `APPLY` operator. Unfortunately, it's still not clear to me how everything fits together, but I will least provide a demonstration using the `APPLY` operator to show two contacts per company that you can use as a starting point:

```
SELECT TOP 10 ct.ID_Contact, ct.NO_CodCompany
FROM tblCompanies cp
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 2 ID_Contact, NO_CodCompany
    FROM tblContacs 
    WHERE NO_CodCompany = cp.ID_Company
        AND DT_DateIncluded < '20170102'
    ORDER BY DT_DateIncluded DESC
) ct
```

`APPLY` works kind of like a `JOIN` on a nested `SELECT` query, where there is no `ON` clause; the join conditional is instead included as part of the `WHERE` clause in the nested `SELECT` statement.

Note the use of `CROSS`. This will exclude companies that have no contacts at all. If you want to include those companies, change it to `OUTER`.

You should also look at what indexes you have defined. A single index on the `tblContacts` table that looks at `NO_CodCompany` and `DT_DateIncluded` (in that order!) might work wonders for this query, especially if it also has `ID_Contact` in the `INCLUDES` clause. Then you could complete the `tblContacts` portion of the query entirely from the index.

Comment: Hello everyone who posted a comment. After adding the changes suggested, still no joy...My goal with this query is to obtain contacts from companies but limited to "n" contacts per company (on the query I used as example, n=2). The query I posted as example does the job perfectly, but it gets "impossibly slow" when I add the date clause in it. This date field is already indexed, and I have already changed the datediff expression to a simple DT_DateIncluded>='20170101'. But still no joy...I would be happy with a different query that performs normally with the date clause or without it.

Comment: @Claudio.hz see my updated answer. And if this helps, I'd appreciate hearing the before and after times.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `DATEDIFF() < 0' try using:

```
and con2.DT_DateIncluded <= '2017-01-01'
```

Also, ensure that there is an index on the `DT_DateIncluded' column.

The reason `DATEDIFF()` runs slow is that using it takes a bit of time to perform the calculation, the query optimizer is (probably) ending up running it for the entire table, and there is (probably) no index to help it select the required rows.

When you remove that clause the query runs faster, but that is probably helped along by the fact that you're only selecting the first two rows in the inner query and ten rows in the outer query, allowing a table scan to be performant enough.

Comment: Thank you Phylyp for your help. I think that, per your comment and others above, datediff() function is better be replaced by a comparison clause.